# Why img is not moving?

Tags: css

I am trying to center an element in a bottom-block div, but it stays to the left. Here is my code:

```css
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.logo img {
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom_block">
  <a class="logo" href="#">
    <img src="Style/img/logo_uniqa.jpg" alt="logo">
  </a>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Side note, I don't think `box-sizing: padding-box;` is valid.

Comment: What about `text-align: center` for your div?

Comment: You may also need a `position:` value in the css either `absolute` or `relative`

Comment: @j08691 [its not](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```css
.logo {
    display: block;    
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.logo img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom_block">
  <a class="logo" href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="logo">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this css:

```
.bottom_block{
    text-align:center;
}
```